# How to generate x509 v3 certificate with SerialNumber field in subject?

Tags: ssl, openssl, certificate, x509certificate, x509

How to generate the x509 v3 certificate with SerialNumber field in subject using openssl command.
Every time i create a certificate with v3 extension i am getting the serialNumber field appended with CN like below

```
    Subject: C=AU, ST=AN, L=CN, O=DUM, OU=DE, CN=1234/serialNumber=5678
```

while the expected one is

```
    Subject: C=AU, ST=AN, L=CN, O=DUM, OU=DE, CN=1234, serialNumber=5678
```

Comment: You are getting it right. It is just openssl representation of the subject that prints serialNumber in subject as `/serialNumber`.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: Use and configuration of standard security technologies would fit the topic definition of development and programming - it's a common enough problem. Yes, there are other SO forums to land this in as well, but I don't think this is especially off topic for here.